# Flash movie in background and position fixed in Chrome => bad behaviour

Tags: css, flash, google-chrome, z-index, swfobject

**Google Chrome is breaking the position fixed of some div elements if a flash movie is playing in the background.**

Example: my header and footer are positioned as fixed (top, bottom). When I scroll the window they stay on the top and bottom in Firefox, Safari (5.1.7), etc, but move along with the content in Chrome.

I use SWFObject 2.2 to place the flash movie.
I've tried all wmodes (transparent, opaque, window)

**HTML Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var fv = {};
  swfobject.embedSWF('background.swf', 'back-flash', '100%', '100%', '10.0.0', 
  'expressinstall.swf', fv, {bgcolor: '#222222', menu: 'false', wmode: 'opaque'}, 
  {id: 'back-flash'});
</script>
```

z-index of the div containing the flash movie is set to -99 
and the z-index of the above elements is set to 99

**CSS Code:**

```
#back-flash-holder{
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -99;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#header{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #ddd;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

Mac OSX, Chrome version is: 19.0.1084.56, Flash Player version: 11.3.300.257

Example: [jsfiddle.net/WE8wv](http://jsfiddle.net/WE8wv/)

Any idea why it isn't working in Chrome while it works in Safari?

Comment: Note: on Windows everything works as supposed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your top and left values to include px. I've had issues with Chrome being too picky about my syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, but including the _px_ makes no diference.